# NetLogo - transferring data between neighboring turtles

Tags: data-transfer, netlogo

Is there any way to transfer data between turtles?
I would like to send and receive data between a turtle and its neighboring turtles, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library, check out Commmunication T-T Example.  ("T-T" is short for "turtle to turtle".)